# Format nested JSON response

Tags: java, json, hibernate, rest

I am facing a problem with formatting JSON as response data. I have a class Player, which has the fields name, id, age, top, middle, and bottom. I have another class Position which has fields id, top, middle, and bottom. Player fields top, middle, and bottom come from Position and set it for Player.

My problem is I am getting JSON response data as:

```
{ id     : 10,
  age    : 16,
  top    : 18,
  middle : 16,
  bottom : 10
}
```

Whereas I want it as:

```
 { id  : 10,
   age : 16,
   position : {
     top    : 18,
     middle : 16,
     bottom : 10
   }
 }
```

Comment: its depends upon your array formation

Comment: Where do you get your response from? What server-side language are you using to produce this output? Is it PHP, Ruby, VB.NET/C#?

Comment: diEcho: this is not array, actually its fields from other class.

Comment: NoLifeKing: am using java RestEasy api

Comment: Then you should be able to set the player-class to contain the position as a property. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have not told how the JSON object is generated as an output. Here you can crate new JSON object as you wanted by organizing the data from the returned out put like given below:

```
var returned={
    "id": 10,
    "age": 16,
    "top": 18,
    "middle": 16,
    "bottom": 10
};

var iWanted={
  "id":returned["id"],
  "age":returned["age"],
  "position":{
        "top":returned["top"],
        "middle":returned["middle"],
        "bottom":returned["bottom"]
      }
};

console.log(iWanted);
```

Comment: Json object is created using restAPI  @Produces("application/json").

Comment: and am not getting how to convert  returned as iWanted using it

Comment: Are you able to assign the restAPI response to any variable ? Could you please elaborate how the response done in restAPI ?